# Crop window on top of the video

Tags: java, android, video, crop

I want to display a  resizable crop window on top of the video.Once user adjusts the window I want to get the width and height of window along with x and y position of the top left corner of the window.
How should I procced with this?Is there any library available for this?

Update-
I am referring to something like this- https://github.com/edmodo/cropper
which we have for image..In my case it's for video and I want to get width and height of window along with x and y position of the top left corner of the window

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to drawing a rectangle overlay over a video? like a rubber band line which can then be resized by the user and you can use that to determine the location and the dimensions of the rectangle to do the cropping?

If so, I would suggest that you look at this example of drawing rubber band lines in Android. You will need to track the mouse/touch events to adjust the location and size of the rubber band lines.

[Draw rubber band line with an ontouchevent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15938066/draw-rubber-band-line-with-an-ontouchevent)

Comment: I am referring to something like this- https://github.com/edmodo/cropper which we have for image..In my case it's for video and I want to get  width and height of window along with x and y position of the top left corner of the window

Comment: The rubber band lines will be drawn by your app. Isn't that right? for that you will already need to know the topX, topY, bottomX and bottomY coordinates, won't you?  I am referring to this call: canvas.drawLine(topX, topY, bottomX, bottomY, paintFill);